# Hsqldb 2.5.0 SYSTEM VERSIONING

Tags: hsqldb

I would like to use the system versioning coming with version 2.5.0 but when I launch a request of the type:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM customer FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 YEAR
```

It does not find any record when there are some which have just been inserted ...

Answer (score 0):

Your query means "return the rows that existed a year ago". Because you inserted the rows recently, or added system versioning recently, the query returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

As I have found some of the things I am looking to do with the system versioning coming with Hsqldb 2.5.x, I allow myself to post this answer.

To retrieve the previous version of a row, which is the last version before the current version, or more simply to find all the UPDATE made for 1 year, simply execute the query:

```
SELECT previous.* FROM customer AS current, customer FOR SYSTEM_TIME
FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 YEAR TO CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS previous
WHERE current.customerid = ? AND previous.customerid = ? AND
current.start = previous.stop;
```

Assuming that:

```
    start: is the column declared as TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START.
    stop: is the column declared as TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END.
    customerid: is the primary key to the customer table, because I have to find the UPDATE for each customer.
```

I now have to find the INSERT and DELETE queries, I would come back for that.

PS: I didn't invent anything, it comes from BD2 documentation, so it may not be optimal, but it works with Hsqldb system versioning.

Edit: This answer is not satisfactory, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741271/how-to-query-system-versioning-of-hsqldb-2-5-1/62747742#62747742) for something much better